# By + past perfect

Tags: past-tense

> By 6:00 she had put her sweater on

Does that mean she was wearing her sweater before 6 and at 6:01 she took it off?

[image]

Comment: It means that at some time before 6.00 she was not wearing her sweater, and she put it on at 5.59 or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It means that **at some point before 6pm she had put her sweater on**. In this specific example where we know that she was not wearing it at 4pm, we could also say it means she put it on at some point between 4pm and 6pm.

When we say that something has been done **by** a particular time (or that something in the future *must* be done by that time) we mean that is has been, or must be done *before* to meet that deadline.

In your specific example, you have two 'snapshots' of time - a picture at 4pm, and one at 6pm. In the second picture, the woman is wearing a cardigan so she must have put it on *before* 6pm in order to appear wearing it at that time. Because we have no images between 4pm and 6pm we cannot say precisely when she put it on, only that she was wearing it **by** 6pm.